# Automatically pass a cookie with each web-service call

Tags: web-services, soap, jax-ws

I have a standalone web-service client. When invoking any of the web-methods an additional "cookie" string must be **implicitly**(not as a web-method parameter) passed to the WS. The WS on the other end must be able to obtain the string and use it. How can this be achieved?

I invoke the service in the following way:

```
Service srv = Service.create(new URL(WSDL), QNAME);
myClassPort = srv.getPort(MyClass.class);
```

What I need is to put some code before the first line, which would make the client send this "cookie" string every time I invoke some remote method via myClassPort. Thx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default `JAX-WS` web services and clients are stateless. When a client makes a request, the server responds and sets a cookie on the connection, if it participates in a session. But, the `JAX-WS` client ignores that cookie and the server treats subsequent requests as new interaction. When the session is enabled, `JAX-WS` client sends the same cookie with each subsequent request so that server can keep track of the client session.

So you should not be using either cookies or HTTP sessions with web services. Return a token ID as part of the response; then the client can send that along with the next request.

Anyway:

JAX-WS web service clients must be configured to maintain session information (such as cookies), using the `javax.xml.ws.session.maintain` property. 
Other web service stacks may have similar mechanisms.

**On the Server Side**

JAX-WS uses some handy annotations defined by *Common Annotations for the Java Platform* ([JSR 250](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=250)), to inject the web service context and declaring lifecycle methods.
`WebServiceContext` holds the context information pertaining to a request being served.

You don't need to implement `javax.xml.rpc.server.ServiceLifecycle`. With `JAX-WS` Web Service all you need to do is mark a field or method with `@Resource`. The type element MUST be either `java.lang.Object` or `javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext`.

```
@WebService
public class HelloWorld {
    @Resource
    private WebServiceContext wsContext;
    public void sayHello(){
        MessageContext mc = wsContext.getMessageContext();
        HttpSession session = ((javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST)).getSession();

     }
}
```

Comment: "So you should not be using either cookies or HTTP sessions with web services. Return a token ID as part of the response; then the client can send that along with the next request."
Thx for your answer! Could you explain why you mentioned that? That was exactly the point to make the client send some ID **implicitly** rather than as an explicit parameter of each web method.

Comment: In my suggestion the client has to send the token ID explicitly. Cookies may be an option if you have control over all clients if this is not the case cookies are usually a no go for web services.

Comment: Could you add more information on the use case where I have control over all clients? Is it possible to use **`java.net.CookieHandler`**, or is setting `javax.xml.ws.session.maintain` the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

There are some misleading answers to this question, so I will attempt to highlight current best practices.  Most of these suggestions are part of the OWASP security guidelines, which I strongly recommend anyone working on web development to review.

1) ALWAYS use temporary (session scoped) cookies.

2) All cookies should be protected and encrypted.

3) Do not pass tokens in request payloads

4) For any requests which return data that may be sent back to the server, include a nonce (single use token) in your responses.

5) later requests should (must) include the nonce and the cookie

Again, my recommendation is to review the OWASP guidelines and proceed accordingly.
You may want to look into using a service provider for authentication - this is much smarter than brewing your own solution as there are literally a million details that all must be correct.  Auth0.com is one of these.